# How to manually implement facebook login and logout using a Button without using the <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton/>?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Is there any workaround to implement facebook login/logout using normal buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is, refer [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

If you want working example, you can refer this-> [FbLogin](https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725)

Comment: It still uses LoginButton right?

Comment: Do you mean LoginButton from fb's sdk?